# What's the fastest way to switch endianness when reading from a file with C++?

Tags: c++, performance, file, endianness

I've been provided a binary file to read, which holds a sequence of raw values. For the sake of simplicity suppose they're unsigned integral values, either 4-byte or 8-byte long. Unfortunately for me, the byte order for these values is incompatible with my processor's endianness (little vs big or vice-versa; never mind about weird PDF-endianness etc.); and I want this data in memory with the proper endianness.

What's the fastest way to do this, considering the fact that I'm reading the data from a file? If it's not worth exploiting this fact, please explain why that is.

Comment: I resort to inline assembly since (i) you're platform-specific at that point anyway, and (ii) it's difficult to solve the problem in well-defined C++.

Comment: Make byte order part of the file format specification. That way you know the byte order in the file, irrespective of who created it. A common choice is to go for network byte order (big endian). For manipulating the file, you can then make use of the [`htonl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html) family of functions to translate between host byte order (whichever that is) and network byte order.

Comment: @Bathsheba - not true. Intrinsics are the way to go for portability without having to deal with the pain of inline asm code. Try __builtin_bswap32 and __builtin_bswap64 for Linux/GCC. Microsoft has similar ones.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: I don't control the file format, the file is just there. I'll clarify that.

Comment: @einpoklum : and the file format doesn't have a fixed byte order ? If so, then how do you know what byte order was used when writing the file ?

Comment: @BitBank: But when should I apply them? Just read the whole thing than byte-swap? Can't I "push down" the byte swapping somehow?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: `To: einpoklum@somewhere.org\nFrom: JoeSmith@somewhere.org\n\nI've exported the data you asked for, it's in /home/jsmith/for_einpoklum.bin , a raw file with big-endian 4-byte unsigned values.\nEnjoy.`

Comment: @einpoklum : ok, so you can use the [`htonl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/htonl.html) family of functions then as suggested earlier. Read a `uint32_t` from the file, and then convert it to host byte order using `ntohl`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Acting on element at a time should be quite slow.

Comment: @einpoklum : measure - don't assume. Sequentially working through the data, converting one word at a time, probably can't be made much faster. You have more chance of improving performance by focusing on the I/O and buffering, and avoiding memory copies.

Comment: https://commandcenter.blogspot.fr/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: @CodyGray: This question is one of the exceptions to that rule.

Comment: The file I/O will take considerably more time than the few instructions needed to convert the byte endianess. Managing the buffers/read amount is the key. Just read a block of data, convert the endianess and work with it. The worst thing to do is read tiny blocks of data at a time. Read the largest data block at a time that makes sense for memory available (e.g. 1MB blocks).

Comment: The fastest way is likely to be the obvious way, if you set your compiler to optimize appropriately (for that translation unit, if not necessarily for the whole program).  It knows, for example, whether it has access to SIMD instructions that can byte-swap or gather-read in the way you require.  And as a bonus, the next author (perhaps you in 6 months time) stands a chance of understanding what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the fact that you're reading the data from a file, the way you switch endianness is going to have insignificant effect on the runtime, compared to what the file-IO does.

What could make a significant difference is how you read the data. Trying to read the bytes out of order would not be a good idea. Simply read the bytes in order, and switch endianness afterwards. This separates the reading and the byte swapping.

What *I* want from the byte swapping code typically, and certainly in a case of reading a file, is that it works for any endianness and doesn't depend on architechture specific instructions.

```
char* buf = read(); // let buf be a pointer to the read buffer
uint32_t v;

// little to native
v = 0;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof v; i++)
    v |= buf[i] << CHAR_BIT * i;

// big to native
v = 0;
for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof v; i++)
    v |= buf[i] << CHAR_BIT * (sizeof v - i);
```

This works whether the native is big, little, or one of the middle endian variety.

Of course, [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/endian/doc/conversion.html) has already implemented these for you, so there is no need to re-implement. Also, there are the [`ntoh?`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htons) family of functions provided by both POSIX and by the windows C library, which can be used to convert big endian to/from native.

Comment: I never said the file was on disk. It could be on a RAM drive. Or it could be on disk, but mmapped.

Comment: @einpoklum most files are on a disk, or a slower device, so if you use a ramdisk, then I recommend mentioning it in the question. Mmapped file from the disk is still very much slower to read than the swapping part, but it does make it irrelevant whether adjacent bytes are read slightly out of order, and you don't perhaps need to use a separate buffer.

Comment: @einpoklum: It doesn't make much difference--regardless of the speed of the device itself, just going through the I/O subsystem is pretty slow compared to byte-swapping. Even if you start with a buffer already in RAM, byte-swapping is still quite a bit faster than reading/writing memory (assuming you're dealing with enough that it's not all in cache).

Answer (score 1):

Not the fastest, but a portable way would be to read the file into an (unsigned) int array, alias the int array to a char one (allowed per strict aliasing rule) and swap bytes in memory.

Fully portable way:

```
swapints(unsigned int *arr, size_t l) {
    unsigned int cur;
    char *ix;
    for (size_t i=0; i<l; i++) {
        int cur;
        char *dest = static_cast<char *>(&cur) + sizeof(int);
        char *src = static_cast<char *>(&(arr[i]));
        for(int j=0; j<sizeof(int); j++) *(--dest) = *(src++);
        arr[i] = cur;
    }
}
```

But if you do not need portability, some systems offer swapping functions. For example BSD systems have `bswap16`, `bswap32` and `bswap64` to swap byte in `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` and `uint_64_t` respectively. No doubt equivalent functions exist in Microsoft or GNU-Linux worlds.

Alternatively, if you know that the file is in *network* order (big endian) and your processor is not, you can use the `ntohs` and `ntohl` functions for respectively `uint16_t` and `uint32_t`.

Remark (per AndrewHenle's comment): whatever the host endianness, `ntohs` and `ntohl` can always be used - simply they are no-ops on big-endian systems

Comment: [`endian.h`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/endian.3.html).  Supposedly [accepted into POSIX.](https://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_514.txt)  Also, if the data is big-endian, `ntoh[l|s]()` is always usable for appropriate data types no matter what the processor endianness is.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: if the processor endianness is network order, the fastest conversion is no conversion at all :-) But I've edited my answer to avoid misleading a reader

Comment: *if the processor endianness is network order, the fastest conversion is no conversion at all*  Yes, any decent implementation should take advantage of that..  For example, per [this copy of `endian.h`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/sys/endian.h), on a little-endian machine:  `#define htole16(x)      ((uint16_t)(x))`

Comment: This will be very slow; and it doesn't utilize the fact that the data must go throw some kind of read buffers before being composed into memory finally.

Comment: @einpoklum: The fastest way, will be a dedicated assembly routine acting on an int array and doing the same thing - but I would first profile all that because I suspect that the time will be 
negligible behind the IO time, and the gain between the assembly routine and the one generated by on optimizing compiler may not be worth be work.